# Executing UPDATE statement with mysqljs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Im using [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) and I'm trying to UPDATE a table but it shows me an error with my SQL sentence.

the documentation states that

```
connection.query('UPDATE users SET foo = ?, bar = ?, baz = ? WHERE id = ?', ['a', 'b', 'c', userId], function(err, results) {
  // ...
});
```

But when I try to do it, the query creates all the variables that I'm sending to the first ?, ignorign the other ones, like this

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5]
sql = 'UPDATE tablename SET col1= ?, col2 = ?, col3= ?, col4 = ? WHERE col5=  ?';

  var query = connection.query(sql, [values], function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
      }
      else {
        connection.end();
      }
  })
```

But the query that gets executes is:

```
UPDATE tablename SET col1= 1, 2, 3, 4, col2 = ?, col3= ?, col4 = ? WHERE col5=  ?';
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing an array of values, you are passing *an array of an array* of values.  Stop doing that.

Comment: to clarify.. `connection.query(sql, values, function(err) {`

Comment: I see, but I was doing that because if I do an INSERT, and pass values like this `connection.query(sql, values, function(err)` , it shows an error, and dont let me save it

Comment: Only inserts the first value, if `values=[1,2,3]` the query is this `INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (1)`, but when I put values between brackets `[values]` `INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (1,2,3)`

Comment: @SebastianChavezIrurzo -- you are saying the behavior of `query()` is difference based on whether the command is INSERT or UPDATE? I have to say, I am very skeptical.  Go back and look at the code again carefully.